# Protractor can't find value from a table

Tags: angularjs, selenium, automation, protractor, cucumber

I have a table that displays search results, and it goes something like this:

```
   <table>
    <tbody _ngcontent-c4="">
      <tr _ngcontent-c4="">
        <td _ngcontent-c4="" class="owner">company name</td>
        <td _ngcontent-c4="" class="name"> other name/a></td>
        <td _ngcontent-c4="" class="status">kasutusel</td>
        <td _ngcontent-c4="" class="approval-status">kooskõlastamata</td>
        <td _ngcontent-c4="" class="topics">value</td>
        <td _ngcontent-c4="" class="last-modified text-nowrap">value</td>
      </tr>

      <tr _ngcontent-c4="">
        <td _ngcontent-c4="" class="owner">value</td>
        <td _ngcontent-c4="" class="name"></td>
        <td _ngcontent-c4="" class="name"></td>
        <td _ngcontent-c4="" class="status">kasutusel</td>
        <td _ngcontent-c4="" class="approval-status">some value/td>
        <td _ngcontent-c4="" class="topics">some value</td>
        <td _ngcontent-c4="" class="last-modified text-nowrap">table value</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

And I can't get protractor to find the first element, like "owner", my code is:

```
        var rows = tabledata.all(by.tagName("tr"));
       var cells = rows.all(by.className("owner"));
       await expect(cells.get(0).getText()).to.eventually.equal("company name");
```

I've get: Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator By(css selector, .owner)

The testcase is like this: 1. go to mainpage, 2. search by string, 3. go to results page and verify the results from the table. I have a feeling it doesn't get any elements from that redirected page, although I've tried browser sleep and wait for angular. When I run the test though, it does go to the redirected page, displays the table, and then ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly find out all `.owner` td as below showing:

```
var owners = tabledata.all(by.css('tr > td.owner'));
expect(owners.get(0).getText()).to.eventually.equal("company name");
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't have this error anymore, but still I put a random text inside the "company name" tags, and test still passes - as if it doesn't actually check the correct value, any ideas?

Comment: So weird, I get the same 'no such element found' error again. Seems to me there has to be some sort of a wait function, what are the possibilities besides angular wait and browser sleep?

Comment: Got it! the answer was in this wait function, now it works: 
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false); //could empty Protractors/Seleniums ChangeDetection on the ControlFlow
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true); //will observe the ControlFlow for new promises again.